# Can't create bibliography while using an elsevier template

Tags: bibliographies, errors, miktex, texmaker

I am using Texmaker 5.0.2.
I have downloaded "Elsevier reference styles" sample manuscript from 
https://www.elsevier.com/authors/author-schemas/latex-instructions

However, I get the following error on compiling the original template-

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \X@mytitlenote 
l.72 \end{frontmatter}

?
```

If I try to play around with the elsarticle-template, I get the following error on compilation-

```
The file could not be saved. Please check if you have write permission.
```

Sometimes I am able to compile, but the references section and citations are blank.

Any help to create the Bibliography would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. I am not quite sure what you are doing. Does that error appear with the template as downloaded? Or did you do some changes before? Where does the bibbliography come into play?

Comment: For the creation of the bibliography, you can have a look at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Creating_a_Bibliography

Comment: Error comes with the template - i make no changes...

Comment: Everything works except the Bibliography component

Comment: I am still running TeX Live 2017, which is a bit out of date by now. But i don't get any errors. It works flawlessly.

Comment: I double checked my Texmaker version, and it is the latest one.  Let me try to run the template on another compiling platform and get back.

Comment: TeXmaker version is completely irrelevant. Your installation of TeX Live or MikTeX matters.

Comment: Okay.  I was thinking it was due hyperref package creating issues.  Can you please elaborate the Tex Live or MikTex installation?

Comment: No, i cannot. You have to wait for someone else to confirm the issue.

Comment: @ArvindSharma I am using the `elsarticle` template and I see no errros. I am using `MikTeX` and its probably 8 months old now. If possible, could you post a MWE of the `.tex` file that is being problematic? by that way we could go and look into the error in detail.

Comment: I have MacTeX2018, and I am able to reproduce the issue you've encountered. The first time you compile `elsarticle-template` and receive the warning message, simply type `r` (for "run") when TeX pauses. Then rerun LaTeX, and the issue no longer surfaces. (I have no idea what may be going on; it may be the case that one or more of the packages loaded by the tex file need to be fixed.) Then run BibTeX and LaTeX twice more. By the way, both the template file and the associated bib file contain various errors of content. E.g., there is `lorentz` instead of `{Lorentz}` in one of the `title` fields.

Comment: If you can't save the file `elsarticle-template.tex` after modifying it, it must be because you don't have write permissions on either the file itself or on the directory in which it's located. The can't-save issue is entirely separate from, and unrelated to, the other issue you've identified.

Comment: @Raaja -- it looks like it's necessary to run the template file under TeXLive2018 in order to reproduce the OP's issue.

Comment: @Johannes_B -- it looks like it's necessary to run the template file under TeXLive2018 in order to reproduce the OP's issue.

Comment: @Mico I didn't catch that from OP's question. I will check with `TeXLive18` distribution later. Looks interesting :D

Comment: @mico That is why I waited for someone else to confirm the issue. The OP did not mention what distribution is in use and doesn't seem to know what it even is.

Comment: @ArvindSharma - Please tell us which TeX distribution you employ. Do note that TeXmaker is just a front end to a TeX distribution; it is not a part of the TeX distribution itself.

Comment: @Mico - I am using Miktex.  The template is also available on Overleaf and works online but when I download it and run it on my PC I get the errors again. https://www.overleaf.com/18918201bvbwjkvsybfk#/71008013/

Comment: @ArvindSharma - Which Version of MikTeX do you employ? How recently did you last perform a full update of all packages?

Comment: @Mico - Miktex version 2.9.6300, and updated all packages 10 days ago.

Comment: @ArvindSharma - Thanks. Does the procedure I recommended in my initial comment (basically: ignore the warning message and keep compiling) work for you?

Comment: @Mico-Yes, it works but the Reference section and citations do not work.

Comment: @ArvindSharma - Please be more specific regarding "... do not work." Do you get errors and/or warning messages? What does the BibTeX log file (with extension .blg) say?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84773/discussion-on-question-by-arvind-sharma-cant-create-bibliography-while-using-an).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

Here's a condensed version of the file `elsarticle-template.tex` -- condensed in the sense that I've stripped out all material not related to creating numeric-style citation call-outs and the formatted bibliography -- along with a corrected form (more about this below) of the bib file that's distributed with the template file.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybibfile.bib}
@article{Dirac1953888,
  title   = "The {Lorentz} transformation and absolute time",
  journal = "Physica",
  volume  = "19",
  number  = "1--12",
  pages   = "888--896",
  year    = "1953",
  doi     = "10.1016/S0031-8914(53)80099-6",
  author  = "Paul A. M. Dirac"
}
@article{Feynman1963118,
  title   = "The theory of a general quantum system interacting 
             with a linear dissipative system",
  journal = "Annals of Physics",
  volume  = "24",
  pages   = "118--173",
  year    = "1963",
  doi     = "10.1016/0003-4916(63)90068-X",
  author  = "Richard P. Feynman and Vernon, Jr., Frank L.", 
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}

\begin{document}
Here are two sample references: \cite{Feynman1963118,Dirac1953888}.
\bibliography{mybibfile}
\end{document}
```

If MikTeX is installed correctly on your system, and if you run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more, you should get the following output:

[image]

If you do *not* get this output, more likely than not something went wrong when you installed MikTeX. Try reinstalling it from scratch and recompiling this file.

---

It's somewhat instructive (and quite depressing, actually) to compare the corrected form of the sample bib file, shown above, with what's provided by the Elsevier template:

```
@article{Dirac1953888,
  title   = "The lorentz transformation and absolute time",
  journal = "Physica ",
  volume  = "19",
  number  = "1-–12",
  pages   = "888--896",
  year    = "1953",
  doi     = "10.1016/S0031-8914(53)80099-6",
  author  = "P.A.M. Dirac"
}

@article{Feynman1963118,
  title   = "The theory of a general quantum system interacting 
             with a linear dissipative system",
  journal = "Annals of Physics ",
  volume  = "24",
  pages   = "118--173",
  year    = "1963",
  doi     = "10.1016/0003-4916(63)90068-X",
  author  = "R.P Feynman and F.L {Vernon Jr.}"
}
```

The following errors and sorry instances of outright sloppiness are readily apparent in in the Elsevier template version:

- In the `title` field of the Dirac entry, note that we have `lorentz` instead of `{Lorentz}`. Since "Lorentz" is a person's surname (full name: Hendrik Antoon Lorentz; 1853-1928), it is *not ok* to lowercase it. Encasing "Lorentz" in curly braces prevents BibTeX from converting it to lowercase if sentence style is employed.
- In the `number` field of the Dirac entry, one finds `"1-–12"` instead of `"1--12"`. Note the weird presence of the unicode-type en-dash character, `–`, after the `first "dash" character,`-`.
- In the `author` field of the Feynman entry, one finds `F.L {Vernon Jr.}` instead of `Vernon, Jr., F. L.`. It is *not ok* to make the name's "junior component" a part of the surname.
- The other author in the Feynman entry should be `R. P. Feynman`, *not* `R.P Feynman`. Do leave spaces between initials, and do terminate truncated names with a period (aka full stop).
- Aside: You should make a habit of providing full first names, not just initials, for all authors and editors. Here: Paul Dirac, Richard Feynman, Frank Lee. That way, if you ever have to employ a bibliography style that writes out full first names, or if the journal you're submitting a paper to makes you use such a bibliography style, you won't have to start fiddling with the bib file to supply the missing information.

Happy BibTeXing!

Comment: Thanks a ton.  Yes, I am able to properly compile your code. I am however curious why I need to run Latex, Bibtex, Latex, Latex, and finally QuickBuild to generate the output in Texmaker using MikTex?  Also, if I switch to Tex Live 2018 too, I am not able to compile a biblography or get citations, though an output (all other sections) are properly generated.

Comment: @ArvindSharma - The LaTeX-BibTeX-LaTeX-LaTeX compilation sequence is the standard method for creating (and subsequently updating) formatted bibliographies and citation call-outs. Please read any introduction to BibTeX to familiarize yourself with this topic.

Comment: @ArvindSharma - If you can’t create the bibliography and citation call-outs with TeXLive as the back-end, it’s most likely because (a) you’re not running BibTeX and/or (b) the document is missing a `\bibliographystyle` statement. What does the blg (bibliography log) file say?

Comment: @Mico- I am using your condensed version of Elsevier template in TexLive.  I do not get any errors but the citations have **?** and no reference section is generated.

Comment: @ArvindSharma - So far, you still haven't stated with any kind of specificity *how* you actually compile your document. However, the presence of `?` instead of real citation call-outs and the absence of a formatted bibliography are both entirely consistent with the hypothesis that you haven't run BibTeX -- or, at least, haven't run it correctly. As I asked in one or two earlier comments, *what is in the file `\jobname.blg`*? For sure, if there is no file named `\jobname.blg`, where `\jobname` is the name of your main tex file, then it's almost certain that you have not run BibTeX.

Comment: @ArvindSharma -  In case you haven't already guessed: BibTeX is the program that creates the formatted bibliography. It actually creates two files: `\jobname.bbl` (the file that contains the formatted bibliography) and `\jobname.blg` (the associated log file). To repeat my question: *What, if anything, is in the .blg file*?

Comment: @Mico- I am using the standard LaTex-BibTex-Latex-Latex compilation.  .blg file contains the following -`This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2018)
Capacity: max_strings=100000, hash_size=100000, hash_prime=85009
The top-level auxiliary file: elsarticle-template.aux
The style file: elsarticle-num.bst
Database file #1: mybibfile.bib
You've used 2 entries,
            2937 wiz_defined-function locations,
            687 strings with 5457 characters,
and the built_in function-call counts, 664 in all, are:`

Comment: `= -- 70
> -- 11
< -- 0
+ -- 5
- -- 3
* -- 54
:= -- 106
add.period$ -- 4
call.type$ -- 2
change.case$ -- 2
chr.to.int$ -- 0
cite$ -- 2
duplicate$ -- 15
empty$ -- 68
format.name$ -- 4
if$ -- 158
int.to.chr$ -- 0
int.to.str$ -- 2
missing$ -- 2
newline$ -- 16
num.names$ -- 2
pop$ -- 7
preamble$ -- 1
purify$ -- 0
quote$ -- 0
skip$ -- 38
stack$ -- 0
substring$ -- 50
swap$ -- 6
text.length$ -- 0
text.prefix$ -- 0
top$ -- 0
type$ -- 0
warning$ -- 0
while$ -- 6
width$ -- 3
write$ -- 27`

Comment: @ArvindSharma - Thanks. And what, if anything, is in the `.bbl` file? Does it look like the file contains two formatted bibliographic entries?

Comment: @Mico- .bbl file contains- `\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\expandafter\ifx\csname url\endcsname\relax
  \def\url#1{\texttt{#1}}\fi
\expandafter\ifx\csname urlprefix\endcsname\relax\def\urlprefix{URL }\fi
\expandafter\ifx\csname href\endcsname\relax
  \def\href#1#2{#2} \def\path#1{#1}\fi

\bibitem{Feynman1963118}
R.~P. Feynman, F.~L. Vernon, Jr., The theory of a general quantum system
  interacting with a linear dissipative system, Annals of Physics 24 (1963)
  118--173.
\newblock \href {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0003-4916(63)90068-X}
  {\path{doi:10.1016/0003-4916(63)90068-X}}.`

Comment: `\bibitem{Dirac1953888}
P.~A.~M. Dirac, The {Lorentz} transformation and absolute time, Physica
  19~(1--12) (1953) 888--896.
\newblock \href {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0031-8914(53)80099-6}
  {\path{doi:10.1016/S0031-8914(53)80099-6}}.

\end{thebibliography}`

Comment: @ArvindSharma - And yet, LaTeX still can't create a pdf file that contains the formatted bibliography? I'm afraid I don't understand what's going on.